# python function executed in the 'run:' context returns the path of the output file, provide that to 'output:' context

Tags: python, output, workflow, snakemake

I have snakemake workflow in which the python function executed in the 'run:' context returns the path of the output file. I want to capture that as a variable in the `Snakefile` provide it to the 'output:' context.

That way I could have my `output:` automatically filled.
I wonder if there is any way to do this in snakemake. Please let me know.

Further information on the python function:
It processes the file provided in the `input:` context and returns a single string which is the path of the output file.

The rule looks like this:

```
rule task01:
    input:
        "path/to/input.tsv"
    run:
        from module import function
        p=function(metadata=metadata)
        # p is the path where the output file needs to be saved
        # For that I would like to access the variable p in the `output:` context below
    output:
        # can I access the variable p here?
```

Comment: Why would you want to have a variable output? The whole point of Snakemake is to be transparent about your in- and outputs, so this defeats the point. What's the actual problem you're facing? You seem to be facing a classic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: I guess for what I wanted to do, `snakemake` is not the right workflow manager.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the variable of interest to a file and read that file where needed to recover the variable content.

Keep in mind that snakemake requires files to be chained by input-output links. If a rule doesn't have the `output` directive it will be effectively ignored unless it is the first rule.

For example:

```py
rule task01:
    input:
        "path/to/input.tsv",
    output:
        "path/to/my-variable.txt", 
    run:
        from module import function
        p=function(metadata=metadata)
        with open(output, "w") as fout:
            fout.writelines()

rule task02:
    input:
        "path/to/my-variable.txt", 
    output:
        'foo.txt',
    run:
        with open(input) as fin:
            p = fin.readlines()
        # do something with p
```

See also this FAQ about [passing variables between rules](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#i-want-to-pass-variables-between-rules-is-that-possible), but you still need your task01 to have the `output` directive.

Comment: Thanks, that takes me closer to the answer. I wanted to use the variable `p` to save the file than doing anything else though, ideally by providing it to `output:` context directly. Would that be possible? I that case I have to write much fewer lines.
I have now clarified this in the question as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link also. I wonder if I can pass the variable `p` (within rule) from `rule:` context to the `output:` context.

Comment: *pass the variable p (within rule) from rule: context to the output: context* Can you explain why you want to do that? What use are you going to make of the output file determined by `p`? See also if [checkpoints](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution) help, but maybe you are trying to do something more contrieved than necessary.

Comment: What I am trying to do is that I want to have `output:` directive as simple as `output: p`. This is in the case where `p` is already a path to the output. Otherwise, I would like to access the variable `p` in the `output:` directive and create output path using that, e.g. `output: f"{p}.csv"`.  I hope this makes things clearer. I will update the question as well to try to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks, for pointing out `checkpoints` as well, @dariober, I will try that.

Comment: Hmm, you answer the question: _why do you want to do A_ with _because I want to do A_. Can you really explain why you want the directive to be "as simple as `output: p`, simplicity is not an end in itself. You seem to want to bend Snakemake to your idea of what Snakemake should be like. Do it the other way round. Learn how Snakemake thinks about the world and write your code accordingly.